# load region by country multi select in ui component magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, country-regions, multiselect

In the Ui-component of Magento 2, I see that we can do this to load region by country.

```
<fieldset name="delivery_area" sortOrder="90">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery Shipping Area</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item><!-- fieldset name -->
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country</item><!-- 'country' - db table column name where country code is saved -->
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item><!-- fieldset name -->
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">state_province</item><!-- 'state_province' - db table column name where region name is saved -->
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">state_province_id</item><!-- 'state_province_id' - db table column name where region id is saved -->
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country</item><!-- 'country' - db table column name where country code is saved -->
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item><!-- country_id field name -->
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
</fieldset>
```

This code worked well, but that only in case they are `select` form.

How about in `multiselect` form?

Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, look like i don't have answer for ui component, but this solution is work for admin form as well, so i'm gonna put it here if any one interested.

So basically, we call block to render country and region instead of ui component.

app/code/Omnyfy/VendorShipping/view/adminhtml/layout/vendorshipping_option_edit.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form" />
            <block class="Omnyfy\VendorShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Option\Delivery\Area" name="omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form_delivery_area" >
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Omnyfy/VendorShipping/Block/Adminhtml/Option/Delivery/Area.php :

```
<?php

namespace Omnyfy\VendorShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Option\Delivery;

class Area extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = [],
        \Omnyfy\VendorShipping\Model\DeliveryRule $deliveryRule
    )
    {
        $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->deliveryRule = $deliveryRule;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('delivery_area', ['legend' => __('Delivery Shipping Area')]);
        $optionsc=$this->countryFactory->toOptionArray();
        $country = $fieldset->addField(
            'country_id',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name' => 'country_id',
                'data-form-part' => 'omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form',
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'title' => __('Country'),
                'values' => $optionsc,
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'region_id',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name' => 'region_id',
                'data-form-part' => 'omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form',
                'label' => __('Region'),
                'title' => __('Region'),
                'values' =>  [
                    0 => [
                        'value' => 0,
                        'label' => '--Please Select Country--'
                        ]
                ]
            ]
        );
        

        /*
           * Add Ajax to the Country select box html output
           */
        $url = $this->getUrl('vendorshipping/option/regionlist');
        $country->setAfterElementHtml("
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    require([
                    'jquery',
                    'mage/template',
                    'jquery/ui',
                    'mage/translate'
                ],
                function($, mageTemplate) {
                   // after we click and mouse out, this "blur" event trigged
                   $('#delivery_area').on('blur', '#country_id', function(event){
                        var countryId = $('#country_id').val();
                        // run ajax to render region by country
                        $.ajax({
                            url : '". $url . "country/' + countryId,
                            type: 'get',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            showLoader:true,
                            success: function(data){
                                // remove old data
                                $('#region_id').empty();
                                // apply new data
                                $('#region_id').append(data.htmlregions);
                            }
                        });
                   })
                }

            );
            </script>"
        );
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_vendor_shipping_option');
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

***Important note:*** We are gonna need to set `'data-form-part' => 'your_ui_component_name'` to make this block connected to the form in ui component, or else, when you press "Save" button, the params won't be uploaded as expected.

Example: `'data-form-part' => 'omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form'`

Here's ui component that i mentioned above, but only for example, it not necessary to copy this file into your code, you just need to ui component name to set `data-form-part`.

app/code/Omnyfy/VendorShipping/view/adminhtml/ui_component/omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form.shipping_option_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Option Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>

    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Omnyfy\VendorShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Option\Edit\Button\Save"/>
            <button name="back" class="Omnyfy\VendorShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Option\Edit\Button\Back"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>omnyfy_vendor_shipping_option_form.shipping_option_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>

    <dataSource name="shipping_option_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="vendorshipping/option/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Omnyfy\VendorShipping\Model\Option\DataProvider" name="shipping_option_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="general" sortOrder="10">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">General</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name" formElement="input" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <label translate="true">Shipping Option Name</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Result:
[image]

Hope it helped someone, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the formElement to multiselect? See line 6

```
<field name="region_id">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item><!-- fieldset name -->
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">state_province</item><!-- 'state_province' - db table column name where region name is saved -->
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">state_province_id</item><!-- 'state_province_id' - db table column name where region id is saved -->
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country</item><!-- 'country' - db table column name where country code is saved -->
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item><!-- country_id field name -->
                    </item>
                </item>
        </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: yes i've tried that, it's show country and region to multiselect, but it won't filter the region by country.